# The test() regular expression returns true/false but when used in if/else condition, it doesn't go inside the condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms

I am currently studying JavaScript and I am having trouble with the if/else condition not working with the test() regular expression. I tried fiddling with if the test() can return true or false and it can but when I am using it with if/else condition, it doesn't proceed in the nest since the alert() is not executed inside. Can you verify what is wrong with my code?

```
<div class="mainBody">
  <span id="firstName">First Name:</span>
  <input id="firstNameInput" type="text" placeholder="First Name" onblur="firstNameValidate()">
  <span id="firstNameResult"></span>
</div>
<p id="test"></p>

<script>
function firstNameValidate() {
  var name = document.getElementById("firstNameInput");
  var result = document.getElementById("firstNameResult");
  var validateName = /[a-zA-Z]/;
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = validateName.test(name.value);
  }
  if (validateName.test(name.value)) {
  alert("Correct");
  }
  else {
  alert("Enter First Name");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` after the line `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML...` which ends the function declaration, the rest of the code is not considered in the function because of that.. move it after your condition.

Comment: Thank you! This is my first post and I'm embarrased for it to be only a typo. I resorted to asking a question here after trying it several times with different code and wondering why the if/else condition doesn't execute.

Comment: No problem, it happens to everyone, having a question closed for typo or duplicate is nothing wrong, one shouldn't take it as a criticism, the main reason is to optimize relevant results when searching for solutions on search engines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the issue is the closing brace of your function, the if/else conditional is out of your function (try indenting your code ALWAYS, that way is easy to avoid/spot those mistakes).

```
function firstNameValidate() {
  var name = document.getElementById("firstNameInput");
  var result = document.getElementById("firstNameResult");
  var validateName = /[a-zA-Z]/;
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = validateName.test(name.value);

  if (validateName.test(name.value)) {
    alert("Correct");
  } else {
    alert("Enter First Name");
  }
}
```

[A working example in codepen](https://codepen.io/feardarkness/pen/xxOQZNE)

Also, a good place to test your regex: https://regex101.com/

If you are having troubles understanding regular expressions, try with https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Good luck!

Comment: Usually questions in which the unexpected behavior is caused by a typo are to be closed, it's not very useful to add elaborated answers..

Comment: Sorry, I thought it may be helpful to show him codepen and regex 101 since he is  learning.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was fiddling with this code and I didn't even notice the issue with the closing brace after several tries. I appreciate the link you provided. I'm trying to learn javascript and I'm actually having a hard time with regex.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: This is a resonably detailed answer, yes the question should be closed (and has) but this does add some useful points for the OP, unlike [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64769910/542251)